# skrollr classic example footer

Tags: html, skrollr

I am trying to teach myself to use the Skrollr plugin properly, I am mainly interested in the classic example listed in the documentation. (http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/classic.html).

My problem is that my footer doesn't appear at the bottom of the page, instead it appears below the first image in my Skrollr gallery. I want to keep the footer separate from #skrollr-body as this gallery would only appears on a specific page.

This is my code, it's essentially a slightly simplified version of the example.

html:

```
<div
class="parallax-image-wrapper parallax-image-wrapper-100"
data-anchor-target="#dragons + .gap"
data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)">
  <div
  class="parallax-image parallax-image-100"
  style="background-image:url(/assets/img/rocks.jpg)"
  data-anchor-target="#dragons + .gap"
  data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0px);"
  data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 50%, 0px);">
  </div>
</div>  
<div
class="parallax-image-wrapper parallax-image-wrapper-100"
data-anchor-target="#bacons + .gap"
data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)">
  <div
  class="parallax-image parallax-image-100"
  style="background-image:url(/assets/img/tiles.jpg)"
  data-anchor-target="#bacons + .gap"
  data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0px);"
  data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 50%, 0px);">
  </div>
</div>
<div
class="parallax-image-wrapper parallax-image-wrapper-100"
data-anchor-target="#kittens + .gap"
data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)">
  <div
  class="parallax-image parallax-image-100"
  style="background-image:url(/assets/img/sky.jpg)"
  data-anchor-target="#kittens + .gap"
  data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0px);"
  data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 50%, 0px);">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="skrollr-body">
  <div id="dragons"></div>
  <div class="gap gap-100"></div>
  <div id="bacons"></div>
  <div class="gap gap-100"></div>
  <div id="kittens"></div>
  <div class="gap gap-100"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  some footer stuff
</div>
```

and css:

```
* {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    html, body {
        height:100%;
    }

    #content {
        height:100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .skrollr-desktop body {
        height:100% !important;
    }

    .parallax-image-wrapper {
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .parallax-image-wrapper-50 {
        height:50%;
        top:-50%;
    }

    .parallax-image-wrapper-100 {
        height:100%;
        top:-100%;
    }

    .parallax-image {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        background-size:cover;
    }

    .parallax-image-50 {
        height:200%;
        top:-50%;
    }

    .parallax-image-100 {
        height:100%;
        top:0;
    }

    .parallax-image.skrollable-between {
        display:block;
    }

    .no-skrollr .parallax-image-wrapper {
        display:none !important;
    }

    #skrollr-body {
        height:100%;
        overflow:visible;
        position:relative;
    }

    .gap {
        background:transparent center no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }

    .skrollr .gap {
        background:transparent !important;
    }

    .gap-50 {
        height:50%;
    }

    .gap-100 {
        height:100%;
    }

    #footer {
        clear: both;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the footer element *inside* `#skrollr-body`. To make everything work on desktop/mobile, the only body content that will reside outside of `#skrollr-body` are your fixed position controls and attributes for the `parallax-image-wrapper` & `parallax-image` sets.

If you require additional "fixed" positioned elements in your layout, you'll need to list those outside `#skrollr-body` setting a `data-anchor-target` attribute for the div, and then call that target #id you created down in the `#skrollr-body` wherever you need it to display.

Like how they do with #dragons, #bacons, & #kittens targets in the classic example docs.